# Laravel multiple dropdown search

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am new to laravel and have a slight issue. I have multiple dropdowns and 3 input textboxes that are used to narrow a search in a single data table. The data table is job history. The dropdowns and inputs are the following:

Class (dropdown),

Type (dropdown),

Job Status (dropdown),

Department (dropdown),

Start Date (input to search jobs from date),

End Date (input to search jobs to date),

Last Called (input for date last called),

My Code is

```
$jobs=Job::where('class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%')
                 ->orwhere('job_status','LIKE','%'.$request->status.'%')
                 ->orwhere('type','LIKE','%'.$request->type.'%')
                 ->orwhere('department','LIKE','%'.$request->department.'%')
                 ->orWhereBetween('date_booked',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
                 ->orWhereBetween('date_last_called',['1970-01-01',$request->last_called])->get();
```

This will only give me the result of one of the criteria(Example: only sorted by class).
I can get it to work if I use 'where' instead of 'orWhere' but the issue is that having all the dropdowns and inputs used is optional. They should be able to only say 2 or 3 dropdowns used if wanted. I could use a lot of if statements but this seems inefficient. For example:

```
 if($request->class && $request->start_date && $request->end_date)
    {
        $jobs = Job::where('class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%')
        ->whereBetween('date_booked',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])->get();
    }
    else if($request->class)
    {
        $jobs = Job::where('class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%')->get();
    }
    else if($request->status)
    {
        $jobs = Job::where('job_status','LIKE','%'.$request->status.'%')->get();
    }
    else if($request->type)
    {
        $jobs = Job::where('type','LIKE','%'.$request->type.'%')->get();
    }
    else if($request->department)
    {
        $jobs = Job::where('department','LIKE','%'.$request->department.'%')->get();
    }
```

...but then would I not need to create an if statement for every permutation? This seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use an OR statement and whereRaw

```
$jobs = Job::whereRaw('? IS NULL OR class=?', [$request->class, $request->class])->whereRaw('? IS NULL OR job_status = ?', [$request->job_status, $request->job_status]);
```

**Edit:**

You don't need to call the get method until you need get the results

```
$jobs = Job::on();

if($request->class && $request->start_date && $request->end_date)
    {
        $jobs = $jobs->where('class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%')
        ->whereBetween('date_booked',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date]);
    }
    if($request->class)
    {
        $jobs = $jobs->where('class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%');
    }
    if($request->status)
    {
        $jobs = $jobs->where( 'job_status', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->status.'%');
    }
    if($request->type)
    {
        $jobs = $jobs->where( 'type','LIKE','%'.$request->type.'%');
    }
    if($request->department)
    {
        $jobs = $jobs->where('department','LIKE','%'.$request->department.'%');
    }


   return $jobs->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I played with it a little but its stopping after 'class'. So it doesn't make it to 'job_status'. Although it does sort by 'class'. Just trying to figure out how to search by all the criteria or only some.

Comment: I've replaced the else if statements with ifs, it should fix the issue

Comment: That does seem closer to the solution although not all the way there. Still it searches for only one criteria. I think it is because, if say, I search 'status' and also 'type'. It will give me only search based on 'type' because the $jobs variable is over ridden from the previous $jobs variable that held the search based on the 'status' criteria. Still don't know how to get both though.

Comment: It's weird because the $jobs variable is not being overriden but every where condition is chained to the previous one, Try checking what the request values are. you could use the toSql method to see how the query is being constructed. Btw you should not concatenate values, try using parameters on your where conditions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was that when I used the 'start_date','end_date', and 'last_called' they were coming up NULL and therefore the search was empty unless I searched using 'where'. Then I would get the search I wanted just not in the dates I wanted. I remedied this by some conditional statements if those values were NULL.

```
        if($request->start_date ==NULL)
        {
            $request->start_date = date("1970-01-01");
        }
        if($request->end_date ==NULL)
        {
            $request->end_date = date("Y-m-d");
        }
        if($request->last_called ==NULL)
        {
            $request->last_called = date("Y-m-d");
        }

        $jobs = Job::where('class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%')
                    ->where('job_status','LIKE','%'.$request->status.'%')
                    ->where('type','LIKE','%'.$request->type.'%')
                    ->where('department','LIKE','%'.$request->department.'%')
                    ->whereBetween('date_booked',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
                    ->whereBetween('date_last_called',['1970-01-01',$request->last_called])->get();

    return $jobs;
```

This fixed it and now it is working perfectly. Thank you.